# React: Accept generic interface as prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript

With Typescript in React, I wish to create a prop type that accepts a generic interface.

```
interface Waffle
{
  startEating: number;
  endEating: number;
  ...
}
interface Pancake
{
  pourSyrup: boolean;
  bake: boolean;
  ...
}
interface classProps
{
  anInterface: ???;
}
class Food extends React.Component<classProps, null>
{ ... }
```

In the example, how do I type the 'anInterface' prop to be of type interface; that is, to accept an object of Waffle or an object of Pancake?

Comment: You could declare a base interface which the `Waffle` and `Pancake` would extend from. Then you can set the `anInterface` prop to be the type of that declared interface: [here's an example of how it can be done](http://shorturl.at/agoUX)

Comment: The key questions is whether you know at compile time what type the component will receive. If so, @luckongas's answer will do it. If not, then the issue is more complicated...

Comment: I agree. If the rendering of the component depends on the type of interface received and the OP doesn't know what type is it, the solution won't work.

Comment: No, I will not know what type it will receive at compile time. It will always be one of the selected interfaces; in this case it will always be a Waffle or a Pancake.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```js
interface Waffle {
    startEating: number;
    endEating: number;
}
interface Pancake {
    pourSyrup: boolean;
    bake: boolean;
}
interface classProps<T> {
    anInterface: T;
}
class Food<T> extends React.Component<classProps<T>, null> {
    ...
}
```

Take into account that if the rendering depends on the type of interface that you are receiving and you don't know the type at compile-time, the generic won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here:

```js
type Props<D, S> = {
  data: D;
  selector: (data: D) => S;
};

const Comp = <D, S>(props: Props<D, S>) => null;

const result = (
  <Comp<number, string>
    data={2}
    selector={(data: number) => "fg"}
  />
); // ok

const result2 = (
  <Comp<number, string> // <--- here is the syntax for component with generic props
    data={2}
    // expected error
    selector={(data: string) => "fg"} 
  />
);
```

Example is take from my [typescript blog](http://catchts.com/react-return-type)